# Meteor App page visit count

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-analytics

I have a Meteor App where I would like to display page visits in certain pages. I have implemented Google Analytics page view tracking for my meteor app using [reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga](https://github.com/reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga/) package , Is there any way that I could retrieve page visit count from my google Analytics dashboard and display in my Meteor App ?

Thanks

This is what I have done so far

Adding reywood:iron-router-ga package

setting up my settings.json

```
{
"public": {
    "ga": {
        "id": "UA-XXXX-Y"
    }
}
```

}

and Configuring my Router

```
Router.configure({
    trackPageView: true
});
```

Comment: Please show your attempt so far otherwise this question is too broad. GA has a REST api that can be used via `HTTP.call()` to get stats that you can then display in the UI. This might be a bit heavyweight for a simple page counter though.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I have Edited my answer , yeah thought of handling the page count in a custom way

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @MichelFloyd, GA is overkill for your needs, and is actually a performance bottleneck for many sites. You don't want to be dependent on an external site for something as trivial as a page counter.

Create a Mongo collection in your database, with a record structure something like this:

```
{
  pageUrl: "/home",
  pageName: "Home page",
  visitCount: 44
}
```

On each page that needs a visit count, do this:

- Subscribe to the page counter
- Increment the page counter on each page view (create if not present)
- Display the page counter somewhere

Comment: Yep , Maybe might need to check if the user is reloading the page by setting up a session variable , so that page view count doesnt increase on refresh :) , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Honestly speaking writing a `page counter` / `count logger` can be a bit scary at first but to tell you the truth it's probably one of the simplest features to implement as a web developer.

You could start off by creating a table in your database with these columns:

```
# text containing the url of the page you wish to log counts for.
1: url
# contains the page name.
2: name
# user id (or ip), to prevent one user adding multiple counts.
3: id
# an this will contain the number of unique visitors of this page.
4: count
```

Now when a user visits the page you would like to add the `counter` to, you:

1. Get the `user id` (or `ip`, once again this is up to you),
2. Get the page name and the `url`,
3. Then inside of the `count` table you just created, update the entry with the `url` of the current page,
4. Add the user `id` and `count` information to the table.

Also remember that by using the `id` / `ip` columns you can not only select the visit count for each individual user, but also for every user at once if you would like to.

Alternatively you could skip the `id` / `ip` columns all together and just log all visits to that page into one row, although I would strongly advice against this, simply to keep your database efficient, manageable and readable.

Hope this helps, good luck and all the best.